# Java For Loop - Change This "Class Variable"

Tags: java

I am new to Java (and asking questions on this site.)and am trying to change the `itemList` variable from `inputs.Items.itemlist1` every time the for loop runs from `itemlist1` to `itemList2` then `itemList3`.
Here is my code:

items.java

```
public class Items {

public static Object[][] itemList1 = new Object[][]{
    {"book", 12.49f, "BOOK"},
    {"Music CD", 14.99f, "OTHERS"},
    {"chocolate bar", 0.85f, "FOOD"},};
public static Object[][] itemList2 = new Object[][]{
    {"imported box of chocolates", 10.00f, "IMPORTED_FOOD"},
    {"imported bottle of perfume", 47.50f, "IMPORTED_OTHER"},};
public static Object[][] itemList3 = new Object[][]{
    {"imported bottle of perfume", 27.99f, "IMPORTED_OTHER"},
    {"bottle of perfume", 18.99f, "OTHERS"},
    {"packet of headache pills", 9.75f, "MEDICAL"},
    {"box of imported chocolates", 11.25f, "IMPORTED_FOOD"}
};

public static Object[] possibleListLength = new Object[]{itemList1.length, itemList2.length, itemList3.length};
public static Object[] possibleList = new Object[][]{itemList1, itemList2, itemList3};
```

}

DetermineItem.java

```
package tax;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class DetermineItem {
    public static String itemPriceString = "";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(inputs.Items.itemList1));
        Object arrayLength = inputs.Items.possibleList.length;
        int arrayLengthInt = (Integer) arrayLength + 1;
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
            System.out.println("Output " + j + ":");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLengthInt; i++) {
                Object[][] itemList = inputs.Items.itemList1;
                Object itemTypeObject = itemList[i][2];
                String itemTypeString = itemTypeObject.toString();
                if (itemTypeString.equals("BOOK") || itemTypeString.equals("FOOD") || itemTypeString.equals("MEDICAL")) {
                    System.out.println("1 " + itemList[i][0] + ": " + itemList[i][1]);
                } else if (itemTypeString.equals("IMPORTED_FOOD") || itemTypeString.equals("IMPORTED_OTHER")) {
                    Object itemPriceObject = itemList[i][1];
                    itemPriceString = itemPriceObject.toString();
                    CalculateImportTax.calculateImportTax();
                    System.out.println("1 " + itemList[i][0] + ": " + CalculateImportTax.price);
                } else {
                    Object itemPriceObject = itemList[i][1];
                    itemPriceString = itemPriceObject.toString();
                    CalculateSalesTax.calculateTax();
                    System.out.println("1 " + itemList[i][0] + ": " + CalculateSalesTax.price);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is stopping you? What and where is your problem?

Comment: I am not sure how to make it automatically change names on every pass through the loop.

Comment: you can't change the names of class members dynamically

Comment: what would you do in this circumstance? I need to be able to hold information of an object, like its cost and name, and grab that information

Comment: If you really need to be able to change the names of things dynamically you can use the HashMap class.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Is it worth it to make them dynamic, or should I just make three separate methods for each itemList.

Comment: I think in this case it would be better to just write 3 separate loops.

Comment: What is not working properly with your current code? You **do not** need to change declarations. Focus on the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is what methods are for.  In outline, and with poorly-chosen method naming (!),

```
    private void doOneList(Object[][] itemList) {
        for (int j=1; j<4; j++) {
           ... do stuff with itemList ...
        }
     }
```

and then in `main`

```
    doOneList(itemList1);
    doOneList(itemList2);
    doOneList(itemList3);
```

I underscore my comment that this is not an off-the-shelf solution, it's just a sketch of how to proceed.

For what it's worth, I'd define a more specific type than arrays of 'Object'.  Something like:

```
 static class Item {
     String description;
     Double tax;
     String type;
 }
```

and then use a single-dimensional Item[]